# Exception - instance error

Tags: php

When you start catching exception and the exceptions autoloader controller error pops up:

```
Argument 1 passed to Controller_Exception:: __construct () must be an instance of Autoloader_Exception, string given, Called in 'source'


try {} catch (Autoloader_Exception $ e){ throw new Controller_Exception ('Some Error');  }}

Controller_Exception class { public function __construct ($ Autoloader_Exception e) { } }
```

Question two, how can I build an exception class? Does anybody know a good example?

Comment: What language are you using? Can you provide some context?

Comment: What was the *first* question?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are using

```
new Controller_Exception ('Some Error')
```

According to the error message 'Some Error' must be an Autoloader_Exception. Depending on what you want to do you could use:

```
new Controller_Exception ($e)
```

For the second question you can read about creating your own exceptions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php).